# Annotations on Preview, why do rectangles now put text in weird orientations?

Tags: preview, macos

[image: When creating a rectangle in Preview sometimes text orientation is weird]
[image]

It appears that this is something happening since Mojave... when drawing a rectangle using the pen tool (Sketch) and doing a rectangle now the text sometimes appear in a weird orientation, let's say for instance upside down...

- When does this orientation happen?
- What steps can I do to make it not happen?
- If it happens, can I rotate the rectangle?

Comment: Why don't you try rotating the rectangle to see if it works?

Comment: Yeah, you could do that... I Googled and using two fingers on the trackpad you can do that but it isn't perfectly aligned...

Comment: There are buttons to rotate a selected object a certain number of degrees. Using that you can align it exactly.

Comment: @jmh where are those? I haven't been able to find them

Comment: if you click on the Tools menu it's towards to bottom of that menu item. Be sure to select the item you want to rotate.

Comment: @jmh oh I see it but that rotates everything not just the rectangle...